# Re-populate dynamic javascript after failed Codeigniter validation

Tags: javascript, php, forms, codeigniter

I have a javascript form that allows users to add data to MySQL table via php.  The form allows the user to dynamically add more data inputs if they need more than the single input that is given initially.

The user clicks on the the "Add Budget Item" button to add more items.

The form in the view looks like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Budget Item" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
  <input type="button" value="Remove Budget Item" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /> 
  <br>
  <p>(All actions apply only to entries with check marked check boxes only.)</p>
</p>

<table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <p>
    <td >
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" value ='<?php echo set_value('chk[]') ?>' />
    </td>
    <td>
    <label>Item/Procedure</label>
    <input type="text" name="itm_nm[]" value ='<?php echo set_value('itm_nm[]') ?>'/>
    </td>
    <td>
    <label for="itm_trig">Trigger/Visit</label>
    <input type="text" class="small"  name="itm_trig[]" value ='<?php echo set_value('itm_trig[]') ?>'/>
    </td>
    <td>
    <td>
    <label for="itm_amt">Budget Amount</label>
    <input type="text" class="small"  name="itm_amt[]" value ='<?php echo set_value('itm_amt[]') ?>'>
    </td>
    </p>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The form is submitted to the validation controller.  Upon a failed validation I would like the form to be repopulated with all the dynamically created fields and their data that was input by the user.

The validation basically looks like this:

```
function index(){


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('itm_nm[]', 'Item Names', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('itm_trig[]', 'Item Triggers/Visits', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('itm_amt[]', 'Item Amounts', 'required|decimal');     

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {


            $this->load->view('build_bud2');

        }
```

When the view is returned, this works fine for the first form item that is not dynamically generated by the user.  But, none of the dynamically generated data fields appear (and are obviously not re-populated with the previously submitted data).

How can I get the dynamically generated data fields to re-appear and be re-populated the same way the initial data does when validation fails?

Comment: you have an extra </p> FYI

Comment: I feel like there's still some code you didn't showed us, specially on the javascript side, if so, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, using a JSON view with Codeigniter and Ajax instead of "posting" the form.

- Submit your form with AJAX, to your PHP script.
- The PHP script takes the fields and sends back a JSON response
- If there is one or more validation error(s), send back an appropriate JSON response with all the fields and errors. The response could be the field ID with the error message, for example.
- The JS takes the JSON response and display the errors (if there are any).

If you want to use a POST anyway, you have, at least, 2 choices:

- Output a JSON representation of what the user entered that will be available in JavaScript. Then, loop trough all the fields and "redo" the field structure based on the JSON representation.
- Or, make a PHP representation of what the user entered (in objects or in an array) and loop trough the fields, in PHP, and display all fields one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

1. Hit Submit Button form
2. Validate input
3. If validation failed, pass the same POST data to the view page (again)
4. Manipulate the passed POST data in view using foreach loops and
   stuff.

By the way, this link may help or give you an idea

[How can I use CodeIgniter's set_value for a field that's an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071774/how-can-i-use-codeigniters-set-value-for-a-field-thats-an-array)